# MediaRecorder and ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()

Tags: android, audio, pipe, android-mediarecorder, amr

My task is to record audio for a long time and send three second files to server for recognition text(I use google for that). If I write directly to file, then I need to reinitialize my recorder to start new file an this takes a lot of time to start and stop mediarecorder. That's why i decided to use ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()That's how I create and initialize my recorder:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] fdPair = new ParcelFileDescriptor[0];
fdPair = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();


ParcelFileDescriptor readFD = fdPair[0];
ParcelFileDescriptor writeFD = fdPair[1];
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(writeFD.getFileDescriptor());
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Then, I create Input stream to read recording data:

```
final ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream reader = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(readFD);
```

Data read from this reader I write to FileOutputStream.

Every 3 seconds I create new file and new FileOutputStream, and send data from previous file to server.

I'am reading bytes according to ARM format(file header, than read every frame's header bit, and then whole frame).

On Nexus One with android 2.3.3, it works well, but on Galaxy S III, Galaxy Nexus and LG p990 it writes something that device player can't read and google can't recognize. Google recognizer returns something like “ok ok” or “######” (looks like files contain some kind of noise).

Does anybody know, why could this work not in the same way for differenet phones/platforms?

Thanks,

P.S. I can't use AudioRecord  – google needs AMR (or speex, or flac)

Comment: "I can't use AudioRecord – google needs AMR (or speex, or flac)" -- you could convert the PCM data into a supported format.

Comment: Is there any fast method to convert pcm to arm?

Comment: Beats me -- I am just mentioning it as a possibility.